# What perk only benefits users who spent more than a decade in cryonic sleep?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, sleep

People are put into a suspended animated state using a cryonic sleep chamber, their brains neither are in deep sleep nor flatline.
Since subjects do not feel anything throughout the entire process, I wonder what kind of perk is only beneficial to those who need to spend more than 10 years in suspended animation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about? Perhaps you could clarify a little, maybe some examples of what you mean by "perk" & when the benefit is supposed to occur, after they come out of cryo or while still in it.

Comment: *"What kind of perk:"* They get two days off work to recover their strength? They get a nice ballpoint pen with the logo of the company? They can warm congratulations and a comradely shake of the hand?

Comment: It's cryonic not cryogenic "sleep".

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking. is it about "why would somebody want to spend 10 year away?" or are you interested in what would happen to crionic if you could still be concious at least somewhat for the duration of the stasis. so far cryogenic "sleep" would entierly suspend your conciense , as your brain doesn't have any activity.

Answer (score 2):

## Investments:

This depends on if you are planning to come back to where you came from. One of the classic science fiction stories, [The Sleeper Awakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sleeper_Awakes) by H.G. Wells, revolves around a man who becomes the richest man on Earth by being placed put to sleep for centuries. Your investments will grow without your presence, so as long as they don't fail or inflation wipes out the profits, you can return a richer man.

## Personality Change:

Okay, this doesn't SOUND like a perk. But what if the complete shut-down of the brain causes the [personality](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2769560/) and/or [identity memory](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17630226/) of a person to reset, as is the case occasionally in people with physical trauma or disease? It isn't a perk to the person, but imagine a government that wants to get rid of undesirables, people with mental issues, the suicidal, or the like? They could retain life memories (or not), but often people who forget their identities can still function, speak, etc. Imagine them being shipped off to a new world where they arrive as blank slates and can be trained for new jobs and programmed to be obedient workers.

## [Transportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penal_transportation)

Not getting from here to there, but getting rid of prisoners, while simultaneously getting out of going to prison. The laws are harsh, and you're sentenced to 10 years in prison for armed robbery. But if you take our little colony ship, then your ten years will pass while you are a corpsicle. Wake up at the other end a free man.

## [Flatliners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatliners)

The person has an out-of-body experience, seeing the dead, experiencing an afterlife, and then returning. Afterwards, the experience profoundly shapes their lives and values ***or*** they find themselves seemingly in contact with the dead.

Answer (score 1):

**Hard restart.**

Sometimes I call to fuss at the IT person because my computer is acting up.  They tell me to restart it.  I ask why.   I am told a computer that runs a long time accumulates unspecified stuff or processes and all that causes problems.  A hard restart gets rid of all that.  More questions by me do not produce enlightment and so I restart the computer with predicted good results.

In some ways you could think of electroshock therapy for depression as being a hard restart for the brain.  Feedforwards loops and unhelpful processes and cut off and the brain restarts, hopefully now without those problematic things.

Your sleepers get a hard restart for the whole body.  The biological programs pick up again at some prior save point.  Hair grows again.  Grumpy nerves that like to remind you of ancient grievances cease their griping and go to work.   You can eat gluten with impunity.  Impunity!  But spicy foods seem super spicy now.  Creativity and humor surge anew and old jokes you no longer thought were funny seem funny again.    You can smell smells that you had forgotten and they are good, and also bad, and all welcome.

Stale old man breath stays, though.  Maybe a few more years of cryo sleep...